# print all the rows of of table into TextArea in javabook database

Tags: java, mysql, database, javafx

In my GUI, there is "Search" menuitem, and it should search the ssn number in the Faculty table and print them into the TextArea in javabook database. However, I only get the last row of the table that has 15 rows.
Here is the Search menuItem that calls the searchDB method.

```
MenuItem search = new MenuItem("Search");
    search.setOnAction((ActionEvent t) -> {
        try{
            searchDB(tArea);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

Here is the searchDB method.

```
public void searchDB(TextArea tArea) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    if (databaseName != null) {
        TextInputDialog dialog = new TextInputDialog();
        dialog.setContentText("Please enter Faculty ssn number follwing by %");
        Optional<String> search_id = dialog.showAndWait();

        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/" +databaseName+ "?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", "scott", "tiger");
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();       
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from Faculty where ssn like '" + search_id.get() + "';");               

            while (resultSet.next())
                tArea.setText(resultSet.getString(1) + "\t" + resultSet.getString(2) + "\t" + resultSet.getString(4) + "\t" + resultSet.getString(5));

        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Can you explain why do I get only the last row of the table? and How to print all the rows of the table in TextArea?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using `setText()`, use `append()` instead. Check the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TextArea.html) for textarea.

Comment: I think you mean [`appendText()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#appendText-java.lang.String-) (you linked the documentation for `JTextArea`).

Comment: @James_D yes I mean't append(), appendText() was depreciated, I have updated the link to point to TextArea instead, thanks.

Comment: It's not deprecated. Now you are linking `java.awt.TextArea`

Comment: It is because it's TextArea he used and not JTextArea that's why the linked was to java.awt.TextArea

Comment: Thank you! It is working but it just prints all in one line. How to separate each row?

Comment: But it's a JavaFX question. Why are you linking Swing or AWT documentation?

Comment: @James_D you are right, my bad, totally forgot about the tags

Comment: @Michelle add `+ System.lineSeparator()` or `+ "\n"`.